# Why is autoshrink not working properly?

Tags: xcode, swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

This problem has been bugging me for quite a while. Oftentimes when I layout a UILabel in Storyboard, I want it to scale with different screen widths. I use this by creating a constraint that sets its width as proportional to the width of its superview.

I then set the size of the text to 300, turn on Autoshrink and set Minimum Size to 1. Ideally this would shrink down the text so that it is the largest possible while fitting the constraints.

But, this happens.

[image: example]

The label on the left **has autoshrink on** and yet the text does not expand to fill (the yellow is simply the label's background, not another view). On the other hand, the label on the right has a fixed size but the same width, showing that the font has much more room to grow.

What's going wrong? Any fixes would be appreciated.

Comment: is the label from edge to edge to both examples?Can you add two more screenshots of what is happening when you have a very big word?

Comment: @Korpel the labels aren't on a colored background, the colors ARE the label's background. Does that make sense?

Comment: ofc it does. Have you tried to have a smaller label instead of using that huge of a label?Instead change the back to a UIView and let the label take a kinda smaller space and then try again?

Comment: @Korpel yes, same behavior. In fact my actual project has a view as a background; I created a new project to test things and demonstrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: may i ask what version you are using? Here is an image of your app trying it on my Xcode

http://postimg.org/image/tpbir896x/3911f279/

Comment: Could you explain more what the problem is? You gave the first label permission to shrink its text, and it did shrink its text. If the text shrinks, it is smaller than the unshrunk version so it takes up less room. You have not allowed the first label itself to get narrower, so there is also some space on both sides. What's the surprise here?

Comment: @matt thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I was confused because ideally autoshrink would shrink the text so that it *just* fits in its width. Instead, it's shrinking to a smaller size. In other words, instead of shrinking little by little until it justs fits (so it would look like the right side), it shrinks in jumps.

Comment: Well, it isn't going to adopt any of the infinite sizes between integers. It's going to shrink by integral font sizes, or something of the sort. So of course it will jump in a way that leaves space if the current size of the label is even a tiny bit too small to accommodate the font at its current size.

Comment: @matt thanks for your help. I've implemented a workaround to shrink manually which works better.

Comment: Brilliant! You should answer your own question (and in 48 hours you can accept your own answer and close the case). I'll certainly be interested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error, I found a workaround to this problem which shrinks fonts at smaller intervals of 1 in order to fit the label's width better.

```
extension UILabel {
func shrinkToFitWidth(margin: CGFloat?) {

    // margin parameter will shrink the font by a certain amount more than necessary. 
    // Use this if you want a label with smaller text on a bigger background. Otherwise, use 0.

    var initialSize : CGSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])

    if initialSize.width > self.frame.size.width
    {
        while initialSize.width > self.frame.size.width
        {
            self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - 1)
            initialSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])
        }
    } else {
        while initialSize.width < self.frame.size.width
        {
            self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize + 1)
            initialSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])
        }
        // went 1 point too large so compensate here
        self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - 1)
    }

    self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - margin!)
}

func shrinkToFitHeight(margin: CGFloat?) {

    // margin parameter will shrink the font by a certain amount more than necessary. 
    // Use this if you want a label with smaller text on a bigger background. Otherwise, use 0.

    var initialSize : CGSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])

    if initialSize.height > self.frame.size.height
    {
        while initialSize.height > self.frame.size.height
        {
            self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - 1)
            initialSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])
        }
    } else {
        while initialSize.height < self.frame.size.height
        {
            self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize + 1)
            initialSize = self.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : self.font])
        }

        // went 1 point too large so compensate here
        self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - 1)
    }

    self.font = self.font.fontWithSize(self.font.pointSize - margin!)
}
```

Note that in order to implement this, it should be called in a view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method so that constraints will have been applied.

Cheers!